# Is it possible to adjust the an elements font size with a mousewheel scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, bind, font-size

I don't have any code but I was just wondering if it is possible in jQuery to increase/decrease an element's font size based on a scroll up/down?

in the best case scenario I would like to increase the font size with a scroll only when the mouse is on that element, just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, you could set the font size on the elements .scroll() Handler. Do you have an concrete Szenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some semi-pseudo code

```
$('#mydiv').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){
  // determines direction of scroll
  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail; 
  var current = $(this).css('font-size');
  // scroll down
  if(delta>0){
    //var pixels = (create a negative pixel ratio system); 
  }else{ //scroll up
    //var pixels = (create a positive pixel ratio system); 
  }
  $(this).css({"font-size" : pixels+"px"});
});
```

Creating something similar to this would work, *but* you will probably run into the problem of your *element* not firing the *scroll* event when there is no *scrollbar* on that element.

This is all dependent on the browser of course, and unfortunately, the mousewheel events aren't the *best* when it comes to cross-browser compatibility (as of the date of this post).

It works here though! (on chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/KqwY2/1/

Comment: This is great!! Much more than I expected.